# Blank screen when switching between GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY and GL_COLOR_ARRAY client states

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es, ios5

I have a drawing function in my iOS 5 app that draws a map of textured hexagons. I'm trying to implement color picking to make the hexagon selection easier, so I built another drawing function that draws the hexagons in various solid colors. Each of these runs fine as long as I never call the alternate function.

The problem happens when I try and draw the solid color map at any point after I've drawn the textured hexagon map - even in different render loops. I am using

```
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

when drawing the solid color map, and

```
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

when drawing the textured map.

But it seems like the texture state is staying active and preventing the solid colors from drawing correctly. As far as I can tell, it's trying to draw the solid colors as textures, even though I've disabled that state. Without any bound texture, they show up blank.

Is there some other function I need to call to successfully switch between color and texture modes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. I had to call

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

in addition to

```
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```